# Why can't my Google App Engine Instance ID include the word "admin"?

Tags: google-app-engine

I was trying to create a new app instance that would be used for the admin site of a site I'm building. When I entered "myappadmin" in the Application Identifier field on the Create an Application page and clicked Check Availability, I received a "Sorry, 'myappadmin' is invalid." message. Is that a bug or a limitation? Or am I just doing something wrong?

Comment: Why do you need a separate app to admin your main app?

Comment: Because I don't want to host admin content on the same site as the consumer site including JS code that could give away api URLs and the like to curious non-admin users.

Comment: You can isolate admin content to a separate URL pattern (/admin) or even an entirely different subdomain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`admin` is not a restricted word for AppEngine Application Identifiers. I've just tried `admin-a` and it worked. Just try to use a name with `-`.
According to this old [Google Group thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/7nMPdjYKOEM), App Engine IDs share a namespace with Gmail accounts. That would explain why so many IDs cannot be used.

Comment: Looks like you're right. Weird since the name I'm using is pretty unique (it's an alternate spelling of an English word and other variants like "myappapi" worked fine). Such strange messaging but I guess maybe they think most people will assume, as I did, there was something wrong with the name and try something else. Still, now that it's known, the "security" part of that (not admitting it matches existing apps so people can just try to hit them) seems moot, but I digress. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

appids must be globally unique within google including existing appids but also email addresses.  If it's not available then there is an account/appid that matches what you are trying.

Comment: You're correct (your answer is the same as Losa's) but I guess I can't split credit for the answer so I went with Losa's given the reference and that he was first. :(